# Can Firebase DB logic duplication be avoided with Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, architecture, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

To avoid rewriting Firebase DB logic in various apps (iOS, Android, Web) we earlier used a service/middle layer to hold this logic. In this way the app never interacts with the DB directly. 
However, in the new architecture with Firebase and Google Cloud Functions, would it be wise to route all DB calls through Cloud Functions or should this be done only selectively based on use case?

In almost all the examples I’ve seen so far, the app directly interacts with Firebase DB and the Cloud Functions are meant to only listen to certain events and used selectively. They are not meant to be a middle layer.
This approach would however lead to the need to duplicate DB logic in all apps. Can this duplication of code be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By moving certain functionality from your application code into Cloud Functions, you will only have to implement that logic once: in JavaScript. This is great for certain logic that you either don't want on the client (too big, too secret, too slow, etc).

But:

- Each client will still need code to access the functionality in Cloud Functions. This can be as simple as a write through the Database SDK, but can also get quite involved.
- The functionality will only be available if the user has a network connection. Unlike client-side functionality, it won't work when the user is disconnected/offline.

Comment: Thanks Frank!  If you use Firebase functions, you lose the real-time DB capabilities and fall back to using regular web API calls. As you pointed out, only for functionalities where there is no need for offline capability and cases where business logic is too complex, I shall use Functions. Everything else can go to Firebase Db directly to leverage its real-time capabilities.

Comment: "If you use Firebase functions, you lose the real-time DB capabilities and fall back to using regular web API calls." Not necessarily. If you have a database-triggered Cloud Function that also writes its results back to the database, the client-side app can still be a database client and get realtime updates. See for an example of this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#perform_database_sanitization_and_maintenance

Comment: Yes, database-triggered Cloud Functions that write back to the DB would help leverage real-time capabilities. As mentioned in the Could Functions documentation, this would be useful in cases where one needs to do maintenance/additional processing of data.  However, I think for the majority of DB operations (CRUD), one shouldn't be using Functions by writing to a queue just to avoid rewriting code. One would be better off working directly with client-side Firebase SDK to leverage offline handling capability even though this means rewriting code for all your different clients separately.